# jquery background color fade in on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the background of the header to fade in after a number of pixel scrolled. With the code below i kinda get it but not much right! Any idea? thanks!

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $(document).scrollTop() > 100 ? $('header').css({
            "background": 1
        }).fadeIn() : $('header').css({
            "background": 0
        }).fadeOut();
    });
})
```

Comment: please show your html part also

Comment: `background:1`? not sure if thats valid css...

Comment: "not much right" - how much not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A combination of Miquel Las Heras and Owen 'Coves' Jones's answers, who both submitted a not completely on-topic or not complete answer.

Use background trasitions (CSS3) and jQuery simultaneously.

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/gcSe8/)**</kbd>

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $("header").addClass("scrolled");
        } else {
            $("header").removeClass("scrolled");
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
    transition: background-color 700ms linear;
}
header.scrolled {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### Update February 3rd, 2017

browser support is very good, and the less performing jQuery solution below should not be used. [Browser support.](http://caniuse.com/css-animation)

### Cross-browser solution

If you want to make it more cross-browser compatible, you can try the color plugin. But from what I've tested, it has quite a bad performance.
<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/gcSe8/1/)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $("header").animate({
                backgroundColor: "red"
            }, 200);
        } else {
            $("header").animate({
                backgroundColor: "blue"
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

Don't forget the plugin itself:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-color/2.1.2/jquery.color.js
```

Comment: @mannygtr No problem. Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you by clicking the "wink". Also, see my edit for cross browser support.

Answer (score 3):

First, as was mentioned in the other answer, you will need to include jQuery UI or the jQuery Color plugin for color animation.

Second, and this is just winging it, but give this the old college try:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $scrollPercent = ($(document).scrollTop() / 100);

        if($scrollPercent <= 1){
            $('header').css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,'+$scrollPercent+')'});
        }
    });
});
```

This should give you a gradual fade in based on the amount down the page you scroll. This means that if you scroll 50 px down, your background color opacity would be set to 50% (50 px down / 100 px height wanted). You can also easily change the amount of height that you want to scroll down to reach full opacity very easily this way.

**EDIT** So it turns out you just want to fade in the color after 100px ... not my gradual fade in. No problem.

Others have pointed out the wonderful (and much better) CSS3 way to do it ... create a transition effect, and add a class on scroll. I won't steal their thunder, but I shall provide an alternative that works back to ancient browsers too.

Add an additional line of HTML inside of your header at the top:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerBackground"></div>
    <!-- other header stuffs -->
</div>
```

Then set its CSS as such:

```
.header {
    position:relative;
}

.headerBackground {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); // for IE8 and below
}
```

Then use the following jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $bg = $('.headerBackground');

        if($(document).scrollTop() >= 100){
            $bg.animate({opacity:1},500); // or whatever speed you want
        } else {
            $bg.animate({opacity:0},500);
        }
    });
});
```

This also has the added benefit of not requiring another library (jQuery UI / jQuery Color plugin). The downside is, of course, the non-semantic HTML. Like I said, just another alternative.

Comment: You don't need all of jQuery-UI; just the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) will suffice.

Comment: i should point out that with using Google's CDN, the library load time would be nothing assuming they had already downloaded it (likely). the only CDN for the jQuery Color plugin is from CDNJS ... still a decent likelihood but smaller. just saying.

Comment: Even though your solution is neat, it is not what the TS wants. He doesn't want a gradual fade-in effect, but a fade-in after 100px. It's not the same thing.

Comment: @BramVanroy ah, fair enough ... let my creativity get ahead of me. edited my answer to include an alternative to the good CSS-based ideas that others had, and also is more in line with what the OP wants.

Comment: Looks nice. Good for older browsers indeed, though - as you might've guessed - the HTML is something to be frowned upon. You might want to add further CSS to make this work, namely `.header{position: relative;} .headerBackground{position: absolute; top: 0; left: ; right: 0; bottom: 0;}`

Comment: @BramVanroy yeah i realized that probably as u were typing it haha. its already in. i didnt add the parent declaration though, good catch.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to create 2 css classes for this type of issues. One for when window is scrolled and one for when it's not:

```
    header { background: transparent; }
    header.scrolled { background: #f2f2f2; }
```

Then the javascript should be:

```
    $(function () {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        if($(document).scrollTop()>100){
          $('header').addClass('scrolled');
        }
        else {
          $('header').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct, but jQuery does not natively support color animation. you need a plugin or jquery-ui for that: http://jqueryui.com/animate/

**EDIT:** actually, your code is kinda wrong. you want to set the backgroundColor to something. background: 1 is invalid css:

so .css({'backgroundColor': 'red'}) and then .css({'backgroundColor': 'blue'})

Comment: [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) will provide color animation without the rest of jQuery-UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support a lot of older browsers you can animate background colours with a combination of jQuery and css3 transitions:

Take the HTML:

```
<div id="myBox">Stuff here</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var myBox = $('#myBox');

myBox.on('click', function (el) {

    myBox.css('background-color', 'red');

}
```

Then click the element #myBox will change its background colour red.  Instantly, with no fade.

If you also put in place the css code:

```
#myBox {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Then any colour changes to the background will be faded over 300ms.  Works on all latest version browsers, but not on IE 9 and below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I ended up using is as follows:

I created a section that I'm fading in and out based on the scroll position.

### CSS

```
.backTex {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: @myGreen;
    //Height
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    //Background-Color
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
        var positionScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(positionScroll <= 499) {
            $(".backTex").css("background-color", "#fff");    
        } else if (positionScroll > 500 && positionScroll < 1100) {
            $(".backTex").css("background-color", "#2ecc71");
        } else {
            $(".backTex").css("background-color", "#fff");
        }
    });
```

As far as compatibility, I haven't noticed any issues between browsers as of yet. Please reply to my post if you experience any. Thanks!